# Insertar por segunda vez en Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

Estoy utilizando Java Hibernate con la base de datos en H2. La base de datos tiene una tabla Trabajador y otra Capacitacion con una relación de muchos a muchos. Para añadir datos a estas tablas cuando estos no existen todo me sale bien, se introducen perfectamente. Pero yo necesito introducir la Capacitacion de un trabajador existente, o unir una Capacitacion existente a un Trabajador existente.

Esta es mi clase Trabajador

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trabajador")
public class Trabajador implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull
private String id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String nombre;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Grupo grupo;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Capacitacion> capacitacions = new ArrayList<>();

public Trabajador() {
}

public Trabajador(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void addCapacitacion(Capacitacion cap) {
    this.capacitacions.add(cap);
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public List<Capacitacion> getCapacitacions() {
    return capacitacions;
}

public void setCapacitacions(List<Capacitacion> capacitacions) {
    this.capacitacions = capacitacions;
}

public Trabajador(String id, String nombre, Grupo grupo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.grupo = grupo;
}

public Grupo getGrupo() {
    return grupo;
}

public void setGrupo(Grupo grupo) {
    this.grupo = grupo;
}
```

}

Y mi clase Capacitacion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "capacitacion")
public class Capacitacion implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull
private String acciones;
private boolean cumplimiento;
private String trimestre;
private String tipo_Accion;

@Id
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fInicio;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fFinal;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "capacitacions")
private List<Trabajador> trabajadors = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Lugar lugar;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Modo_formacion modo_formacion;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Responsable responsable;

public Capacitacion() {
}

public Capacitacion(String acciones, boolean cumplimiento, String trimestre, 
    String tipo_Accion, Date fInicio, Date fFinal, Lugar lugar, 
    Modo_formacion modo_formacion, Responsable responsable) {
    this.acciones = acciones;
    this.cumplimiento = cumplimiento;
    this.trimestre = trimestre;
    this.tipo_Accion = tipo_Accion;
    this.fInicio = fInicio;
    this.fFinal = fFinal;
    this.lugar = lugar;
    this.modo_formacion = modo_formacion;
    this.responsable = responsable;
}

public void addTrabajador(Trabajador trabajador) {
    this.trabajadors.add(trabajador);
    trabajador.addCapacitacion(this);
}

public String getAcciones() {
    return acciones;
}

public void setAcciones(String acciones) {
    this.acciones = acciones;
}

public boolean isCumplimiento() {
    return cumplimiento;
}

public void setCumplimiento(boolean cumplimiento) {
    this.cumplimiento = cumplimiento;
}

public String getTrimestre() {
    return trimestre;
}

public void setTrimestre(String trimestre) {
    this.trimestre = trimestre;
}

public String getTipo_Accion() {
    return tipo_Accion;
}

public void setTipo_Accion(String tipo_Accion) {
    this.tipo_Accion = tipo_Accion;
}

public List<Trabajador> getTrabajadors() {
    return trabajadors;
}

public void setTrabajadors(List<Trabajador> trabajadors) {
    this.trabajadors = trabajadors;
}

public Date getfInicio() {
    return fInicio;
}

public void setfInicio(Date fInicio) {
    this.fInicio = fInicio;
}

public Date getfFinal() {
    return fFinal;
}

public void setfFinal(Date fFinal) {
    this.fFinal = fFinal;
}

public Lugar getLugar() {
    return lugar;
}

public void setLugar(Lugar lugar) {
    this.lugar = lugar;
}

public Modo_formacion getModo_formacion() {
    return modo_formacion;
}

public void setModo_formacion(Modo_formacion modo_formacion) {
    this.modo_formacion = modo_formacion;
}

public Responsable getResponsable() {
    return responsable;
}

public void setResponsable(Responsable responsable) {
    this.responsable = responsable;
}
```

}

para inserta utilizo el siguiente código

```
Trabajador t = new Trabajador("88010565413", "Dulce", null);
    Lugar lugar = new Lugar("CMPSS");
    Modo_formacion modo_formacion= new Modo_formacion("SEM");
    Responsable r = new Responsable("Director");
    String sDate1 = "Mayo-2019";
    String sDate2 = "Septiembre-2019";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").parse(sDate1);
    Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").parse(sDate2);

    Capacitacion c = new Capacitacion("Autopreparación JavaScript", true, 
    "1er Trimestre", "plan", date, date2, lugar, modo_formacion, r);

    c.addTrabajador(t);
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    sesion.persist(t);
    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    sesion.close();
```

Cuando inserto un Trabajador con su Capacitación por primera vez lo inserta perfecto pero cuando a ese mismo Trabajador le quiero insertar otra Capacitación me da error.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartirnos qué error te da?

Answer (score 0):

En una relación muchos a muchos debes de hacer la referencia a ambos lados.
Por ejemplo aqui:

```
c.addTrabajador(t);
```

Relacionas capacitación con trabajador, pero te falta

```
t.addCapacitacion(c);
```

Esto es porque en una relación muchos a muchos se genera una tabla intermedia con los ids de cada una de las tablas como llave. Si no haces referencia a ambos lados, en esta tabla intermedia solo un `id` tiene valor y el otro no.

Por otra parte veo que te falta la anotacion `@JoinTable`:

`JoinTable:` Esta anotacion contiene la informacion sobre la tabla que realiza la relacion muchos a muchos es decir la tabla intermedia que te comento.
Tiene estos atributos

`name:` Nombre de la tabla que realiza la relacion muchos a muchos

`joinColumns:` Contiene cada una de las columnas que forman la clave primaria de esta clase que estamos definiendo. Cada columna se indica mediante una anotacion
 @JoinColumn y en el atributo name contiene el nombre de la columna.

`inverseJoinColumns:` Contiene cada una de las columnas que forman la clave primaria de la clase con la que tenemos la relacion. Cada columna se indica mediante una anotacion @JoinColumn y en el atributo name contiene el nombre de la columna.

Ejemplo entre módulos y profesores:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="ProfesorModulo",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="IdProfesor")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="IdModulo")})
    private Set<Modulo> modulos=new HashSet<>();
```

A pesar de que se supone que en una relación muchos a muchos no hay un lado padre de la relación, para hibernate si lo hay y es donde esta la anotacion `JoinTable` que da la información de esta tabla intermedia.
Te pongo un ejemplo porque desconozco la lógica de tu modelo de negocio. Tu sabrás si esta anotación va en trabajador o en capacitación.